Creating labels for a variable confuses gtsummary
I have a particular problem with labeling categorical variables using {gtsummary}.
When I label the levels of a variable, {gtsummary} does not work properly.
Assume the following data:
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)
library(cobalt)

# Create data and add a categorical variable named hello with five levels:

data <- lalonde
hello <- sample(1:5, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
data$hello <- as.factor(hello)

# Labels:
levels(data$hello) <- c("hello_1", "hello_2", "hello_3", "hello_4", "hello_5")

# Now we specify the variables we want to include in our table1:

vars <- c("hello")

# Now we create table 1:

datasvy <- survey::svydesign(~1, data = data, strata = ~treat)

table1 <- tbl_svysummary(
  datasvy,
  by = treat,
  include = all_of(vars),
  statistic = list(
    all_categorical() ~ "{n}({p}%)"
  ),
  percent = "col",
  digits = list(
    all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1)
  )
)
table1 <- as.data.frame(table1)

Now this is the result:



Characteristic
Group 0 (N = 429)
Group 1 (N = 185)




hello
NA
NA


hello_1
91(NA%)
40(NA%)


hello_2
71(NA%)
35(NA%)


hello_3
82(NA%)
31(NA%)


hello_4
86(NA%)
37(NA%)


hello_5
99(NA%)
42(NA%)



Is there a solution to that?
When I do not use the labels, everything works fine.
Reprex:
library(gtsummary)

data <- cobalt::lalonde
hello <- sample(1:5, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
data$hello <- as.factor(hello)
levels(data$hello) <- c("hello_1", "hello_2", "hello_3", "hello_4", "hello_5")

# Now we specify the variables we want to include in our table1:
vars <- c("hello")

# Now we create table 1:
survey::svydesign(~1, data = data, strata = ~treat) |> 
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = treat,
    include = all_of(vars),
    statistic = list(
      all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"
    ),
    percent = "column",
    digits = list(
      all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1)
    )
  ) |> 
  as_kable()
#> Warning in svydesign.default(~1, data = data, strata = ~treat): No weights or
#> probabilities supplied, assuming equal probability
Characteristic  0, N = 429  1, N = 185
hello       
hello_1 86 (NA%)    43 (NA%)
hello_2 86 (NA%)    33 (NA%)
hello_3 96 (NA%)    35 (NA%)
hello_4 87 (NA%)    39 (NA%)
hello_5 74 (NA%)    35 (NA%)

Created on 2024-11-25 with reprex v2.1.1

I can't replicate your issue. Can you use a proper reprex (reprex.tidyverse.com), which will evaluate in a fresh environment?
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '2.0.3'

# Create data and add a categorical variable named hello with five levels:
data <- cobalt::lalonde
hello <- sample(1:5, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
data$hello <- as.factor(hello)
levels(data$hello) <- c("hello_1", "hello_2", "hello_3", "hello_4", "hello_5")
# Now we specify the variables we want to include in our table1:
vars <- c("hello")

# Now we create table 1:
survey::svydesign(~1, data = data, strata = ~treat) |> 
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = treat,
    include = all_of(vars),
    statistic = list(
      all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"
    ),
    percent = "column",
    digits = list(
      all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1)
    )
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
#> Warning in svydesign.default(~1, data = data, strata = ~treat): No weights or
#> probabilities supplied, assuming equal probability




Characteristic
0 N = 429
1 N = 185




hello




hello_1
88 (20.5%)
37 (20.0%)


hello_2
93 (21.7%)
35 (18.9%)


hello_3
88 (20.5%)
37 (20.0%)


hello_4
85 (19.8%)
36 (19.5%)


hello_5
75 (17.5%)
40 (21.6%)



Created on 2024-11-25 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you so much. I edited. Does that help?

If I have a moment, I may look into it. Perhaps you could update your package, and run the reprex I created to ensure there isn't something else going on

I'd like to suggest using surveytable instead. It's easy to use and gives you all the estimates that you might be looking for.
# Create data
data <- cobalt::lalonde
hello <- sample(1:5, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
data$hello <- as.factor(hello)
levels(data$hello) <- c("hello_1", "hello_2", "hello_3", "hello_4", "hello_5")

# For surveytable, treat needs to be a factor
data$treat = as.factor(data$treat)
datasvy = survey::svydesign(~1, data = data, strata = ~treat)

# surveytable
library(surveytable)
set_survey(datasvy)

tab_subset("hello", "treat")

Output:
                      hello (treat = 0) {datasvy}                      
┌─────────┬────┬────────┬────┬────┬─────┬─────────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Level   │  n │ Number │ SE │ LL │  UL │ Percent │  SE │   LL │   UL │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_1 │ 85 │     85 │  8 │ 70 │ 103 │    19.8 │ 1.9 │ 16.1 │ 23.9 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_2 │ 99 │     99 │  9 │ 83 │ 118 │    23.1 │ 2   │ 19.2 │ 27.4 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_3 │ 90 │     90 │  8 │ 75 │ 108 │    21   │ 2   │ 17.2 │ 25.1 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_4 │ 73 │     73 │  8 │ 59 │  90 │    17   │ 1.8 │ 13.6 │ 20.9 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_5 │ 82 │     82 │  8 │ 67 │ 100 │    19.1 │ 1.9 │ 15.5 │ 23.2 │
└─────────┴────┴────────┴────┴────┴─────┴─────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
  N = 429.                                                             

                     hello (treat = 1) {datasvy}                      
┌─────────┬────┬────────┬────┬────┬────┬─────────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Level   │  n │ Number │ SE │ LL │ UL │ Percent │  SE │   LL │   UL │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_1 │ 50 │     50 │  6 │ 39 │ 64 │    27   │ 3.3 │ 20.8 │ 34.1 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_2 │ 33 │     33 │  5 │ 24 │ 46 │    17.8 │ 2.8 │ 12.6 │ 24.1 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_3 │ 36 │     36 │  5 │ 27 │ 49 │    19.5 │ 2.9 │ 14   │ 25.9 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_4 │ 33 │     33 │  5 │ 24 │ 46 │    17.8 │ 2.8 │ 12.6 │ 24.1 │
├─────────┼────┼────────┼────┼────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ hello_5 │ 33 │     33 │  5 │ 24 │ 46 │    17.8 │ 2.8 │ 12.6 │ 24.1 │
└─────────┴────┴────────┴────┴────┴────┴─────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
  N = 185.                                                            


